# how to implement a function when cancel button is clicked return 0 but when save is clicked return 1 and refresh grid

Tags: c#, datagrid

i have an update form which opens as showDialog. i notice when i click on save my update process goes through, closes form and refresh datagrid on parent form and when cancel button is click it closes form and also refreshes datagrid. how do i prevent datagrid from refresh when cancel button is clicked, am thinking of doing a public int declaration to return 1 when save is clicked and 0 when cancel is clicked but can't figure out how to do so. below is code for calling update form from parent form

```
   private void kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            frmUpdate f2 = new frmUpdate();


            f2.lblClientID.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ClientID"].Value.ToString();
            f2.lblClearinAgentID.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Clearing_Agent_ID"].Value.ToString();
            f2.textboxClientCode.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Client Code"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxClientName.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Client Name"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxPostalAddress.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Postal Address"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxTelephone.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Telephone"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxFax.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Fax"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxEmailAddress1.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["E-mail Address 1"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxEmailAddress2.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["E-mail Address 2"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxEmailAddress3.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["E-mail Address 3"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxWebsite.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Website"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxChargeRate.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Charge Rate"].Value.ToString();
            //f2.lblTotalDeposit.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Total Deposit"].Value.ToString();
            //f2.lblAccountBal.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Account Balance"].Value.ToString();

            f2.ShowDialog();
            kryptonbtnDelete.Enabled = false;

   private void kryptonbtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(null, null);

    }
```

and inside update form which displays as dialog to parent form i tried something like that

```
      private void kryptonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmUpdate_FormClosing(null,null);
    }

    private void frmUpdate_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DialogResult != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

dialog result from save click method

```
      DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Update this Client?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Client information successfully Updated", "Updating Client(s) Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (rowsUpdated > 0)
                    {
                    }
                }

                else if (result == DialogResult.No)
                {

                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of a call to Form.ShowDialog is a DialogResult value.  This value is taken by the Form engine directly from the DialogResult property of the Button clicked. If the button has any value for this property different from DialogResult.None then this button will close the form and its DialogResult property is returned by the call to ShowDialog()

So if you have a button on your frmUpdate with its DialogResult set to OK then

```
if(f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK))
  // User hits the OK button, refresh
else
  // No refresh here...
```

Of course you don't need to handle yourself the closing process of the frmUpdate form. It is automatically handled by the Form engine

Comment: its set to YesNo in the button save method

Comment: Then the return value is DialogResult.Yes or DialogResult.No. Can you show the relevant part of the save method?

Comment: its solved now, i had to modify my save and cancel button in the designer and set them to DialogResult = ok and cancel respectively and i checked it a message box and got appropriate results on button click of each. ty

Comment: its solved now, i had to modify my save and cancel button in the designer and set them to DialogResult = ok and cancel respectively and i checked it with a message box and got appropriate results on button click of each with a dispose to return those values. ty